# minecraft pe- wont let me change skin on custom skin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Recently, I updated minecraft. I downloaded a skin and then went back on minecraft. I click custom skins and then I click the skin I want. However, my screen will turn black and then it goes back to my home screen. I tried this multiple times but it did the same. I also tried it again with different skins, but it still didn't work. Is there a reason why?

Answer (score -2):

You Have To Turn On Local Server Multiplayer.